# css grid flex box - why my image can't filled the entire designated div box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am beginner in HTML5 and CSS3. Apologies if the question is very basic. 
I am trying the develop a responsive website and I am working my way through mobile size to the desk top size.
The problem I am experiencing is that even thought my div has room for the photo to expand fully, but the image does not fully expand to be adjusted with the rest of the web site. 
Here is my html5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/page-main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/footer.css">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- fonts -->
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <section class="cover-photo-home-page-box">
          <div class="cover-photo-container">
            <img class="cover-photo" src="./img/Cover.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="text-next-coverphoto-home">
            <h1 class="heading-home-index">Autumn is coming</h1>
            <p>
            The weather is getting colder and colder. you’d better put on some more clothes. Good news, we have some warm hoodie for you. For you guys the camping is literally made for you – warm, comfortable and casual at the same time. For you ladies, you have the choice between the Sunday hoodie or the Camper. Great no?
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>

      <section class="middle-grid-box-container-home">
        <!-- <div class="photo-banner"> -->
          <a href="./woman.html" class="middle-grid-left-box-container-home">
            <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="./img/Banner-Top-Men.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
          <div class="middle-grid-right-box-container-home">
            <a href="./men.html" class="middle-grid-right-top-box-container-home">
              <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="./img/Banner-Top-Men.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="./men.html" class="middle-grid-right-bottom-box-container-home">
              <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="./img/Banner-Top-Men.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </section>
```

and here is my code for css

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-container{
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.cover-photo-home-page-box{
  display: -webkit-flex; /* For support in a series of Webkit browsers */
  display: -ms-flex; /* For support in IE 10 */
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.text-next-coverphoto-home{
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.cover-photo-container{
  z-index: -1;
  order:1;
}

.cover-photo{
  width: 100%;
}

.heading-home-index{
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 3rem;
}


/*css style for the middle grid*/
.middle-grid-box-container-home,.middle-grid-right-box-container-home{
  display: -webkit-flex; /* For support in a series of Webkit browsers */
  display: -ms-flex; /* For support in IE 10 */
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

 .middle-grid-left-box-container-home img {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .middle-grid-right-box-container-home img{
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Now I am not sure why photos are not lined up properly 
here is the screen shot of the result. 
[image]

It is really appreciated if anyone could give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the images are of different dimensions, so you need to change the below CSS.

```
 .middle-grid-left-box-container-home img {
   width: 100%;
   max-width:350px;
   height:auto;
 }
 .middle-grid-right-box-container-home img{
    width: 100%;
   max-width:350px;
   height:auto;
 }
```

Here we set the max width to the width of the smallest image width, thus all the images will have the same width. To preserve the scale of the image, I have set the `height:auto`, so that the image remain symmetrical.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-container{
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.cover-photo-home-page-box{
  display: -webkit-flex; /* For support in a series of Webkit browsers */
  display: -ms-flex; /* For support in IE 10 */
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.text-next-coverphoto-home{
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.cover-photo-container{
  z-index: -1;
  order:1;
}

.cover-photo{
  width: 100%;
}

.heading-home-index{
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 3rem;
}


/*css style for the middle grid*/
.middle-grid-box-container-home,.middle-grid-right-box-container-home{
  display: -webkit-flex; /* For support in a series of Webkit browsers */
  display: -ms-flex; /* For support in IE 10 */
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

 .middle-grid-left-box-container-home img {
   width: 100%;
   max-width:350px;
   height:auto;
 }
 .middle-grid-right-box-container-home img{
    width: 100%;
   max-width:350px;
   height:auto;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/page-main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/footer.css">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- fonts -->
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <section class="cover-photo-home-page-box">
          <div class="cover-photo-container">
            <img class="cover-photo" src="./img/Cover.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="text-next-coverphoto-home">
            <h1 class="heading-home-index">Autumn is coming</h1>
            <p>
            The weather is getting colder and colder. you’d better put on some more clothes. Good news, we have some warm hoodie for you. For you guys the camping is literally made for you – warm, comfortable and casual at the same time. For you ladies, you have the choice between the Sunday hoodie or the Camper. Great no?
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>

      <section class="middle-grid-box-container-home">
        <!-- <div class="photo-banner"> -->
          <a href="./woman.html" class="middle-grid-left-box-container-home">
            <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
          </a>
          <div class="middle-grid-right-box-container-home">
            <a href="./men.html" class="middle-grid-right-top-box-container-home">
              <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x150" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="./men.html" class="middle-grid-right-bottom-box-container-home">
              <img class="middle-grid-banner-photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </section>
```

Comment: Thanks Naren, My Goal is to have a grid some thing similar to this website: https://herschel.com/, So when it is in smartphone size screen, all the images looks stack. When the size of the screen is bigger for example the size of the lap top, I would like to have a grid similar to what this website is https://herschel.com/ in bigger screen, also in this website it seems like photos are all different sizes, but when it is in mobile view they are all stack nicely on top of each other. and as the screen size grows the girding system adjust with.